# C# ASP.NET Passing if else statement string value to another string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in my page

```
 public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

       private string myquery = null;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           usertype = Session["usertype"].ToString();
            {


                if (usertype == "admin")
                {
                    string myquery = @"SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status  FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    string myquery = @"SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status  FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "' and status = '1'";
                }

            }
            connectDB();
        }
}
```

How i can set my `myquery` string value to my if else statement in my pageload class? My current code always set `myquery` to `null`.

Comment: You are declaring "myquery" again in if condition, remove string keyword in if cand else condition and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
{

   private string myquery = string.Emplty; //Try use this
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       usertype = Session["usertype"].ToString();

            if (usertype == "admin")
            {
                myquery = @"SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status  FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                myquery = @"SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status  FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "' and status = '1'";
            }

        connectDB();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if / else statement, you're declaring myquery a second time. If you remove the string keyword, you should be golden;

```
  if (usertype == "admin")
        {
            myquery = @"SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            myquery = @"SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status  FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "' and status = '1'";
        }
```

Currently, the new variables that you're creating in your if / else statement are being lost due to them falling out of scope the step after creation, so you can't access them either.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql data reader to read data from sql server

```
 SqlCommand command ;
 if (usertype == "admin")
    {
          command = new SqlCommand("SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "'",connection);
connection.Open();

        }
        else
        {
  command = new SqlCommand("SELECT jobId, odometerReading, jobDescription, status  FROM joborder Where truck_id = '" + truck_id + "' and status = '1'",connection);
    connection.Open();
        }
      SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```